# Как сделать смежный запрос в WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Я создал тип данных projects, и к нему создал две таксономии sections - иерархический тип (как рубрики), objects - не иерархический тип (как метки). Соответственно запись принадлежит к какой-то рубрике, а к записи принадлежат несколько меток. Как я могу вывести на странице все записи принадлежащие одновременно к рубрике и к метке?

Например: 
**Рубрики** - "Мультфильмы", "Фильмы". 
**Метки** - "детские", "драма", "18+" и т.д.

---

Как вывести записи относящиеся к рубрике **"Мультфильмы"** с метками **"18+"** ?

Answer (score 1):

Я не уверен на 100%, что это заработает потому что без вашего проекта не могу проверить на ошибки. Но суть именно такая.

Только подставьте свои id для рубрик.

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'projects',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'sections',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => 1
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'objects',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array(2,3)
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);

// Проверяем есть ли посты
if($query->have_posts()) {

    // Проблегаемся циклом
    while($query->have_posts()){
        $query->the_post();

        // Вывод поста

    }

}


?>
```